# How to properly use Android Activity Recognition API in expo

Tags: react-native, expo, activity-recognition

I was wondering if it is possible to get the current activity of the user in expo with the Android Activity Recognition API and iOS similar. I'm willing to get the moment that the user changes from driving to walking or vice-versa.

I've already tried the expo-location package but did not find good results.

Thanks!